# unable to run an external javascript using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Totally newbie about JS.

I need to use an external script which modifies some elements in the current page accessing it as a bookmarklet.

If I modify the html source code of the web page inserting the following < script > lines:

```
s=document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
s.src='script.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

it works fine. But if I create a javascript: bookmarklet with the same lines, I obtain a blank page with the following string:

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
```

whereas, if I create a bookmarklet adding the line

```
void(null);
```

to previous ones, the web page does not disapper but the script is not executed.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common practice is to simply use a self-executing function expression, something like this:

```
(function () {
  var s=document.createElement('script');
  s.type='text/javascript';
  s.src='script.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}());
```

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.src='script.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}());
```

The function will return `undefined` (no return value supplied) preventing the navigation.

Note also that this will avoid creating global variables (like `s`) that can overlap with other variables used on the page, because all variables are created in the scope of the anonymous function.