# Why does my Javascript return [object HTMLScriptElement] instead of expected text?

Tags: java, javascript

I am having similar issues from

[unable to run an external javascript using a bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222417/unable-to-run-an-external-javascript-using-a-bookmarklet).

But I am executing my JavaScript inside a Java application via injecting script headers into the current DOM loaded via Java application.

This problem seems to occur randomly. Some cases it returns `[object HTMLScriptElement]` and other times returns the text...

When I `alert()` the object, it returns text!

I have tried `return String(hi);` but still no effect.

```
function returnsomeText(){
    var hi = someArray.join(':');
    alert(hi); //returns text:text:text:text as expected.
    return hi; //returns [object HTMLScriptElement]
}
```

I am very confused to as what is causing this problem! If JavaScript returns `[object HTMLScriptElement]` then my Java application cannot process the text.

This question is in more detail here:

[Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to execute Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732618/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying)

Comment: What is `someArray`? How can you tell it's returning `[object HTMLScriptElement]`?

Comment: if all else fails I guess you could try `''+hi` to force it to be a string. that doesn't actually answer the question though.

Comment: @Spudley: `[object HTLMScriptElement]` is the result of coercing a `<script>` element to a string anyway, so the result will not change.  The problem isn't with the code here, it's where `returnsomeText()` is being called that's likely the issue.  We need to see more code.

Comment: Hi Kim,

Can you return hi.ToString();?

Comment: @Kim, glad to here it, ill undelete my Answer!

Comment: @Kim you said "occur randomly" - so how can you be so sure it's working? Don't you need to wait some time and verify it's not happening again?

Comment: there's something fishy going on if replacing `String(hi)` with `hi.toString()` solves the problem (overwriting the global `String()` would do it...); assuming `someArray` is actually an array, adding `toString()` is superfluous: `join()` already returns a string on any conforming ECMAScript implementation; also, the string representation of a script node is apparently `'[object HTMLScriptElement]'` in the given implementation, so `hi.toString()` shouldn't have fixed anything even if `hi` were a node - you'd have to use `hi.firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: I don't think Kim is showing us the code which causes the problem...

Comment: @Christoph: details are here....this problem still not fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732618/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying

Answer (score 7):

Try `return hi.toString();`

Comment: @Box9: he did and Kim Jong Woo said "Wow that worked" so I removed the Can you and the ?

Comment: Hi Kim, mplungjan was just helping format my code so it was more of an answer rather than a question. Not sure where the -1 vote came from though!! this answer was posted by me :)

Comment: Kim: it says EDITED by me, but Wraith will get the rep. I just changed the "Can you" to "Try" and removed the question mark. I also changed ToString to toString and voted this back up

Comment: @WraithNath and @mplungjan, sorry I take my comment back.

Comment: @Box you can notify people only one at a time, meaning only the first `@` is taken into account - mplungjan will never see your last comment. The author of the commented Answer or Question will always get notification by the way for any comment made on his/her Answer or Question. Last but not least, you can use the first 3 letters e.g. @mpl will work just fine. :)

Comment: @Box yeah.. learned of all this only recently myself after posting in `Meta` website, so decided to spread that knowledge around to the best of my ability. :)

Comment: oops sry I was quite drunk lastnight.

Comment: hi please see this question, it is much more detailed, with codes provided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732618/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying

Comment: @KimJongWoo feel free to delete your earlier comment about rep theft. Thanks

Comment: @Sha how does SO know the difference between two people with identical first 3 letters? Should happen one day..

Comment: @mpl it doesn't know, the message is sent to the most recently active member. For example if Kim would have been called "mpl Jong Woo" this very message would still reach you since you commented after him, and to reach him I could use "@mplJongWoo" - note that blank spaces must be removed as well.

Comment: sorry to inform you guys bu this is not the correct answer. Unaccepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

TRY adding .text somewhere like:

```
function returnsomeText(){
    var hi = someArray.join(':');
    alert(hi); //returns text:text:text:text as expected.
    return hi.text;
}
```

HERE is a demo:

```
document.write(document.body.children[3]); //writes [object HTMLScriptElement]
document.write(document.body.children[3].text); //writes text data
```

Answer (score 0):

try hi.outerHTML
and there is also an innerHTML, just saying so it may come handy someday

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).