# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to execute Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, nullpointerexception

I am trying to execute Javascript function called "`returnAllLinkTexts()`" on the DOM html page loaded via my Java application. Below line is executed by a Swing Buton.

```
myscript = browser.executeJavascript("returnAllLinkTexts()").toString(); //Line 407
```

Once in a while I get the following exception. The Java application does not terminate or crash.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException com.demo.Main$BigButtonListener.actionPerformed(Main.java:407)
```

I have tried the following to keep retrying about 20 times but it doesn't even reach this point. Exception is raised immediately @ 407.

```
int st = 0;
while (myscript == null){
 myscript = browser.executeJavascript("gogo()").toString();                              if (myscript != null) break;
 if (shit == 20) break;
 sht++;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

This is the Javascript function `returnAllLinkTexts();`

```
function returnAllLinkTexts(){  
var mydata = new Array();

$('a', document).each(function() {
    mydata.push($(this).text()); 
});

return mydata;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of why `returnAllLinkTexts` is breaking (thus you get null) is when it's called before jQuery was loaded.

If possible, try calling `browser.executeJavascript` after the page finished loading otherwise check for null as others already suggested and you can keep trying to invoke it (using timer for example) until it's not null.

Edit: since you're already using the return value as string, you can return string to begin with, for example:

```
return mydata.join(",");
```

Will return the links text separated with comma.

Comment: This is in the right direction but jQuery is loaded already. This Java exception only seems to occur when returnAllLinkTexts is used....if it's just a simple text, then no Java NullPointerExceptions.... I've tried to invoke it 100 loops which took about a minute, but it's still null....then other times it's working fine....totally frustrated with this right now.

Comment: @Kim weird indeed, see my edit though - if you'll return ordinary string from within the JS function it might solve the problem.

Comment: I think this is the problem because when I remove the jQuery functions and methods from returnAllLinkTexts();, everything seems kosher. when I add any jQuery function, trouble brews

Answer (score 1):

You're calling toString() on a potentially null object.

-> Firstly, I would surround with a **try-catch block**

But the question is **why is the return value a possible-null**?
Check your *return value* in the function..

Nur

Comment: I have provided the function above....but I don't see why it would return null. There are links on the page with 100% certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't unconditionally call toString() on a return value which may be  null.  Always check first for null!